# How to properly unit test mongoDB CRUD result

Tags: mongodb, go, testing, grpc

My application mostly consists of CRUDs to/from MongoDB using `mongo-go-drive` package. This function is one of gRPC server services and all it does is calling database method `action.GetProducts(ctx)` and it returns `*mongo.cursor`. Then the result is decoded. For each document, I put the document content into a singular product struct, then append it to products slices (the `GetProductsResponse` struct is made using gRPC proto `repeated GetProductResponse` type). After appending all product into `GetProductsResponse`, I return the response to gRPC client.

I am also new to testing in general, how should I break down the function and do the mocking (how to mock the cursor?) for unit testing? Is it even necessary in the first place to do unit test on the function even though all it does is appending the result, or should I just go straight for the integration test and skip the unit test since it involves database I/O?

```
func (s *Server) GetProducts(ctx context.Context, in *pb.EmptyRequest) (*pb.GetProductsResponse, error) {
    cursor, err := action.GetProducts(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    products := pb.GetProductsResponse{}

    res := model.Product{}

    for cursor.Next(ctx) {
        // Convert document to above struct
        err := cursor.Decode(&res)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to decode document: %v", err)
        }

        product := &pb.GetProductResponse{ProductId: res.Product_id.Hex(), Name: res.Name, Price: res.Price, Qty: int32(res.Qty)}

        products.Products = append(products.Products, product)
    }

    return &products, nil
}
```

Comment: This kind of code is hard to unit test, because you mostly repeat the code you write for DB interaction. This has the downside that both can be wrong as well, so the results are not that useful. What I tend to do instead is to cover the code using integration/E2E tests, i.e. using a real DB in a test setup. Things like Docker make it easy to spin up a DB for testing that you can throw away afterwards.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I see. I was thinking I should just do integration test and entirely ditch unit testing for this kind of functions as well. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you interact with the DB is not unit testing anymore, because you're integrating with another external system.

Anyway, I use to define my "repository" layer function this way:

```
package repo

var FetchUserById = func(id string) (*model.User, error){
    // here the real logic
    return user, err
}
```

and then, when I have to test my "service" layer logic, I would mock the entire "repository" layer this way:

```
repo.FetchUserById = func(id string) (*model.User, err) {
   return myMockedUser, nil
}
```

Comment: If I do integration testing, I don't need to mock the repo though do I?

Comment: no in that case not. Of course it's better to have a containerised version of the database and to apply and remove the DB changes for every test.